# Bash/unix, how to copy all contents (files/subdirs) from one folder to another and keep folder structure

Tags: bash, unix, copy, subdirectory

My structure:

Folder a, include files 1.txt, 2.c, 3.h;
Folder b, include files and subdir: 2.txt, 7.h, /folder subC including 8.h

```
A 
|
  1.txt
  2.c
  3.h

B
|
  2.txt
  7.h
  subC
  |
   8.h
```

Now I want to copy all in Folder b same structure into Folder a?

Copy -rf want work due to dirs and files to keep structure also.

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: @Mikael : Either `cp -r ....` or `rsync -r ... `. _rsync_ gives you more options, `cp` is simpler to use.

Answer (score 0):

`cp -r` preserves the structure if possible. If there are no clashes between file and directory names, the following should work:

```
cp -r B/* A
```

Tested with

```sh
mkdir {A,B}
touch A/{1.txt,2.c,3.h}
touch B/{2.txt,7.h}
mkdir B/subC
touch B/subC/8.h
cp -r B/* A

tree A
A
├── 1.txt
├── 2.c
├── 2.txt
├── 3.h
├── 7.h
└── subC
    └── 8.h
```